# onCreateOptionsMenu + onPrepareOptionsMenu conflict

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm building an app using an appDrawer using [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)
Everything was going really fine and I decided to add an action button in the action bar !

I therefore used [that tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/) to make it.

This problem is that in this second tutorial, when I add this :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

My app force closes throwing this exception :

[image: NullPointerException]

It's seems like there is a conflict with the onPrepareOptionsMenu that I used for the previous tutorial : the appDrawer. Here is the code throwing the exception :

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

If you have any idea of what could be this conflict, I'd gladly collect and try them out !

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on line 161? My guess is that `mDrawerLayout` is null. However, without seeing where you assign that variable, it is nearly impossible to tell you why it is null.

Comment: I haven't, I'll try it out and tell you afterwards. About where I assign the variable, I linked the tutorial I followed instead of copy/pasting everything to make the post clearer.

Comment: Linking to the tutorial doesn't mean that your code is identical- it is possible that you made a typo somewhere. If you believe that there is an issue with the tutorial, I would contact the author. Without seeing more code, the most likely culprit is that your Activity's layout doesn't contain a `DrawerLayout` with the correct ID, and thus `findViewById()` is returning null in `onCreate()`. Start by ensuring that you are inflating the correct layout and that it has the correct Views in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer to that question, in that code :

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I call "**R.id.action_settings**" which can't be called since it was in the default **res/menu/main.xm**l while I'm not using **res/menu/activity_main_actions.xml**

Here is the answer :

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Thanks a lot to Tanis. 7x for helping me debugging that one.